# How to disable Live View Code Finder in Brackets

Tags: adobe, brackets, adobe-brackets

In Adobe Brackets, I have a HTML file open with live view on, when I click on an element in Live View (i.e. Chrome); It automatically scrolls to that elements code in Brackets. I find this very annoying since I have to keep scrolling back to where I was.

Is there a way to disable this feature?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This can be disabled by setting "livedev.enableReverseInspect": false in the preferences file.

For more info [click here](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/How-to-Use-Brackets#preferences).

Answer (score -1):

"There's a toggle `View > Live Preview Highlight` that you can use to disable and re-enable this feature."

[Source](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/11502)

Comment: No, Thats a different feature. I'm talking about when It SCROLLS to the code when you click the LIVE VIEW.

Comment: Then I don't know. Perhaps try asking on their github instead, if you don't get any answers here :)